# Creating an XML object collection

Tags: json, xml, dictionary, object

I have an XML file and that needs to be converted into a specific json format with Items in it.
Items will be a collection where it can have 1 or 2 items in it based on my XML file. When i am `trying to create a dictonary object it is only reading 1st parent tag.
**Format I want **

```
{
  "batch": {
    "source": "Test",
    "items": [
      {
        "identifier": "Item1",
        "type": "input-data",
        "data": "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",
        "priority": "NORMAL"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My XML Sample - my XML can have multiple FinancialInputData tags in it.

```
<Type></Type>
<EventType></EventType>
<DocumentID></DocumentID>
<Contract>
<AssetClass></AssetClass>
<ContractType></ContractType>
<Product>
<Classification>
<IDType></IDType>
<ID></ID>
</Classification>
<Identification>
<UPI></UPI>
</Identification>
</Product>
<CryptoAsset></CryptoAsset>
</Contract>
<Transaction>
<UniqueTransactionID></UniqueTransactionID>
<ExecutionVenue></ExecutionVenue>
<Price>
<Currency></Currency>
<Price></Price>
<Quotation></Quotation>
</Price>
</Transaction>
</FinancialInputData>`
```

Based on my FinancialInputData tag items collection should increase.

I tried creation an dictionary object with some hard coded tags and making items as collection but when i tried that it is only reading 1st FinancialInputData tag.